# How to normalize varying data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

consider the following dataframe. I have the columns 'product', 'buys', 'buy_again', 'again_index'.

PS: index is buy_again/buys.

```
product   buys   buy_again   again_index
a          3       2          0.667
b          40      10         0.25
c          2       1          0.5
d          420     70         0.166
e          87      21         0.241
f          28      4          0.142
```

Now over here, the numbers for buys and buy_again are very skewed and it is unfair to compare product d to product a based on its index. I want to normalize the data using pandas in such a way that the index can be used to directly compare one product to another irrespective of it being new (eg: one with just 3 buys) or old (eg: one with 420 buys) so that the index can be my deciding factor, for a products performance.

Comment: Do you have and temporal data in your dataframe? Perhaps the date from which a product is available?

Comment: Yeah I can add that, will it help?

Comment: There is no single proper solution to your question, its a matter of trial and error.
Personally, I would try to normalize the amount of bought items by time, since it is the main factor of difference in the example above. Stating the date a product was put to sale and knowing the current date would enable such normalization.

Comment: So if I add the date from activation till today, how can I use that to normalize the data. Something like buys/days_active and then divide buy_agains with this to get an index, will that be accurate?

Comment: I’d start with that. You can load the normalized df and add it to your original post.